# Flutter - How to insert stateful widget at the top of a ListView.separated?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `ListView.separated` which initially contains two stateful widgets that say: `Hello  2` and `Hello 3`.

After some time, I want to insert a stateful widget saying `Hello 1` at the top of the `ListView.separated`.

I expect the `ListView.separated` to show `Hello 1`, `Hello 2`, `Hello 3`.

Unfortunately, when I do this, `Hello 3` gets duplicated instead of `Hello 1` getting added to the top of the `ListView.separated`. It now shows `Hello 2`, `Hello 3`, `Hello 3`.

All of this works fine if I use stateless widgets. If I use `StatefulWidget`, the order gets messed up and widgets get duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
bool _condition = false;

Widget build(context) {
  return ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      _condition ? yourNewWidget : Container(),
      ListView.separated(
        shrinkWrap: true, // needed 
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), // needed 
        itemBuilder: (c, i) => Text("Text = ${i}"),
        separatorBuilder: (c, i) => Divider(),
        itemCount: 100,
      )
    ],
  )
}
```

When you have a `newWidget` up and ready make sure you call `setState(())` to update `build()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, this won't allow `newWidget` to scroll with the `ListView.separated`, will it?

Comment: No, it won't allow newWidget to scroll. Do you need that?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to scroll with the rest of the list.

Comment: Let me know one more thing before I submit a new solution, do you also have item below the `ListView` like some button or another widget?

Comment: I guess I could use a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Column` as the child and use that to achieve the list (and then manually create dividers). However, I was hoping to understand why `ListView.separated` has issues when you insert a widget to the top of the list...

Comment: No, I do not have another widget below the list.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just tested it and it works perfectly. Thanks!